# Function to number paragraphs starting from a sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-traversing

```
<!-- html -->
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<h1>Title 2</h1>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>

<!--jQuery -->
$('#numPara').bind('click', function(){
    var i=0;
    var bouton = $(this);
    $('p').nextUntil('h1').each(function(index, element){
        console.log(element);
        $(element).prepend((index+1) + '.' + (index+1) + " ");
        bouton.attr('disabled', false);
        });

    });
});
```

Question: How can I number the paragraphs from the number of the title? I already 'bind' my button to number the paragraphs but it doesn't apply on the first paragraph of each section and it doesn't follow the number of the title. Teacher told me that I should put limits but I've been searching for a few hours now and I have no idea how to do it. Thank you for any help.

```
Example : 1. Title1
          1.1 paragraph1
          1.2 paragraph2
          1.3 paragraph3
          2. Title2
          2.1 paragraph1
          2.2 paragraph2
          2.3 paragraph3
```

Comment: Try instead to do `$('h1').each` and then for each `h1`, do `$(this).next('p').nextUntil('h1')`

Comment: you could use `<ol>` and `<li>`

Answer (score 1):

Given that html, place this code accordingly when you need to run the script:

```
$('h1').each(function(hIndex, element){
    hIndex++;
    var next = $(this).next();
    var pIndex = 0;
    while (next.is('p')) {
        pIndex++;
        next.prepend(hIndex + '.' + pIndex + ' ');
        next = next.next();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z28KQ/

Comment: Thank you very much...it's the "var next = $(this).next();" that I was missing...very appreciated...I understand now

Comment: @user2359135 Glad I helped you! BTW, if that solved your problem, choose this answer as the correct one.